# Toxiproxy Windows Binary Usage

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to use toxiproxy Windows binary - https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy.

The issue is that official README absolutely lacks instructions of how to use toxiproxy Windows binary.
I found that it's possible to declare proxies in JSON file and use -config option with a path to this file.

The issue though that I it's not stated anywhere how to declare toxics in JSON file - i.e. latency, timeout, etc.. Having only proxy itself is absolutely useless to me - I need to simulate delays.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

HTTP API can be used to create proxies and toxics.

https://github.com/shopify/toxiproxy#http-api

Closing.